# Is there a single word that can describe something that breathes/produces fire?

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a word that I can use to describe something that "breathes" (**out**) fire. If there is no such word, I can create it myself, much like Stephen King created Pyrokinesis.

Is there such a word?

**To clarify:**
I am using the word as an adjective, and as part of a description in a document related to a novel I'm writing (sci-fi). So, for example:

### Blablablabus Blabladens

**Size:** 2feet
**Height:** 1foot
**Social Structure:** antisocial
**Notes:** bla, bla bla.
**Diet:** bla.
**Special Features:** bla bla bla bla.
**Pyrogenetic(?) Abilities:** Breathes fire using blablabla organ.

See where I use Pyrogenetic? That's where I want to use the word. However, I'm not sure what word would be correct, and I don't want to use "Fire-breathing" if I don't *have* to.

### After some deliberation and the highest voted answer so far:

I decided to create my own word(s): Ignigenesis/(Ignigenic).

Comment: Breathes in or breathes out?

Comment: *Firebreathing* should work.

Comment: *Ignirespiration* = Latin *Fire breathing*, but that's not a real word.

Comment: @JasperLoy: I'm looking for a word that means those words :D
If I have to create one... then I'll just do that :/

Comment: Not exactly an everyday word, but *pyrorespiration* [has been used a few times](http://www.c2comics.com/c2cblog/?s=To+search,+type+and+hit+Go).

Comment: [Pyrogenetic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pyrogenetic) is a geological term.

Comment: @dr65: not *only* a geological term, but yes. That is why I don't want to use it.

Comment: So is this contrasted with other creatures that can create fire in other ways, or with other breath weapons, or is this ability entirely unique to this creature? That influences whether it makes sense to have it as a category heading at all.

Comment: It seems to me that you want _fire spitting_, not fire breathing. The creature produces fire, but does not use fire for respiration.

Comment: @dotancohen you can breathe something out without using it for respiration. For example we breathe out carbon dioxide but it's not something we use for respiration (in general our bodies don't take much in cause they are already saturated). So the animals in this case "breathe" fire out, and it's completely valid :)

Comment: If it's being used to describe an organ it maybe that a little more detail is called for then you get with "fire-breathing".  There are many ways to achieve the effect and appearance of "breathing fire".  If it has nothing to do with respiration it's a misnomer.  Gasses and fluids can both achieve the same effect.  Maybe indicate which one this animal uses?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only "real" adjective that describes something that breathes fire is *fire-breathing*.  This isn't a common word, but then again, fire-breathing objects aren't all that common either.

If you want to make up a word, the Latin for *fire-breathing* is *ignirespiratory*.  As FumbleFingers notes in a comment, *[pyrorespiration](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pyrorespiration)* has been used before (9 results on Google), so you might want to give that a look.  (It mixes Greek and Latin, but that's not too big an issue - look at *television*.)

Dictionary.com has an entry for the obsolete *[ignivomous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Ignivomous)*, which means *vomiting fire*.

Comment: Thanks for the help :). I'm beginning to feel I have to create a word.

Comment: How about joining igni- with expiration or exhalation somehow?

Comment: I've created my own word :)!
Ignogenesis (n) / Ignogenetic (adj): producing fire.

Comment: @Hugo: Ignixhalation?

Comment: *Fire-breathing* isn't really all that *uncommon* either. For instance, I've quite often heard mother-in-laws described that way.

Comment: @Roland: Actually, it should be *igni-*, not *igno-*: *Ignigenesis* and *ignigenetic* :)

Comment: Wouldn't pyrokinetic also work? It's used for controlling fire, but could also loosy encompass this.

Comment: @dr65: okie dokie :D

Comment: "Firebreathing dragon" is a pretty common phrase.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the best possible word, I suggest that it not be a Greek-Latin hybrid, especially since there are so many correctly formed pure options that are perfectly fine.

There are **igniferous, flammigerous, flammiferous, flammivomous**, all actual English words, the first three roughly meaning "fire-bringing/causing/producing". The fourth ("flame-spewing") would be the most precise.

You could also name your category by a noun, like **igni-/flammipotency**, "power by fire" and replace the entire phrase *Pyrogenetic(?) Abilities* with it. Or you could use the adjective, **igni-/flammipotent**, "powerful by fire"; these words are based on actual Latin words with the same meaning but do not exist as English words (yet).

I'd generally prefer some compound with *flamm-*, because that has more connotations of active, flowing flames, as opposed to *igni-*, which is perhaps a slightly more static fire.

Based on Greek, you could use **pyropneumatic** ("breathing fire") which does not exist yet but would be correctly formed. The existing English word **pyrogenetic** ("capable of creating fire") is usually used for inflammable materials, but it would do well here too.

Comment: I like pyropneumatic a lot for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly there isn't an everyday word for 'fire breathing dragon'!
In mythology I think 'drake' might be the closest.

Comment: @JasperLoy: it is also a word for Dragon :D